Lightning force close detection
    ┌────────────────────────────────────┐       ┌────────────────────────────┐
    │ outputs contain revocation script? ├──yes──► force close w/ penalty = 3 │
    └──────────────┬─────────────────────┘       └────────────────────────────┘
                   no
    ┌──────────────▼──────────────────────────┐
    │ outputs contain other lightning script? ├──┐
    └──────────────┬──────────────────────────┘  │
                   no                           yes
    ┌──────────────▼─────────────┐               │
    │ sequence starts with 0x80  │      ┌────────▼────────┐
    │           and              ├──────► force close = 2 │
    │ locktime starts with 0x20? │      └─────────────────┘
    └──────────────┬─────────────┘
                   no
         ┌─────────▼────────┐
         │ mutual close = 1 │
         └──────────────────┘

I saw this diagram in mempool space code here. How is the sequence starts with and locktime starts with used to detect force close? Is there some convention, or is this important for the underlying protocol?
